# Porting PHP 5.2.14 to Symbian

Tags: php, mysql, apache, symbian

I am new here. I am not a very experienced programmer in fact i don't know any C, but attempted this anyway. I used the PAMP stack developed by nokia and saw, that it had been discontinued so i tried porting the latest php to it. 
After a lot of trials and errors i finally did it. However when attempting to start Apache on symbian it just crashes with no error(when trying to load the new php). I saw there was an stderr.log file, bit said it could not load it.
In Symbian's case, php is just a dll(names with a so extension) and is only about 3 megabytes.  I tried debuggin apache, but got nowhere really.

The question is where is the problem. In compiling the DLL there were some warnings, but they were in the original port of php 5.2.2 as well minus some from php 5.2.14.
I really have no idea where the problem is OR how to fix it.

Comment: @user529018 - serverfault.com ... please

Comment: Lol, sorry i did not even know there was an answer. And i am new. I cant know everything around here

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say where the problem is without seeing the output of your build and what the panic code is.

It could be:

1. missing capabilities
2. that you are linking to library that is not present on the device
3. a binary compatibility issue

I suggest you make your .PKG file install an empty file to c:\resource\ErrRd, which causes the panic note to be shown on the device when you try to start an application exe (in your case apache).

If it says "Feature not supported", it is a DLL problem (2 or 3)
If it says "Permission not granted" (or something similar), there are missing capabilities (1)

Just add this line to your .PKG file to have the panic note shown:

```
""-"c:\resource\ErrRd"
```